# iOS7 Sprite Kit how to disable touches on a sprite to make it "tap through"?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, user-interaction

I know that for traditional UIViews, I can set "enable user interaction" flag to NO, and the view will no longer respond to touches, letting the views below them receive touches.

Is there some way to implement the same "tap through" functionality in Sprite Kit? So far I've only seen people using "Touches began", getting the point and asking the scene for nodes at that point.

The problem with this approach is - if I want to add overlays on top of sprites (like monster life points, etc) they will also respond to touches. So far I'm trying to avoid this problem by creating custom classes for different nodes, and then having a very big if statement, checking the class of each node.

**Is there a better way to achieve "tap through" functionality for sprite kit?**

Comment: Can you just set `node.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES` on a subclassed SKSpriteNode, then the touch delegates will called within the class. Hence, you can handle the touch for the sprite within its class.

However, by default, the `userInteractionEnabled` property is set to `NO`. Hence the touch on a sprite is, by default, a "tap through".

So, for the overlays you want, create custom classes for the sprites, implement the `touchesBegan:` and other delegates within that class and while initialising, set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it multiple times, this made my life so much easier

Comment: @akashg - Same issue here, and I'm not sure how this solved it. I have a scene (userInteractionEnabled = NO) containing a custom sprite with the occasional overlay (userInteractionEnabled = NO) passing over it. The custom sprite hears the taps just fine until an overlay is over it, and then they hear nothing. How do I make the taps pass through the overlay to sprite beneath? Thanks!

Comment: @wanderlust - it depends upon the node tree. Because the userInteractionEnabled property of the overlays is set to NO, then the tap will be intercepted by the overlays' parent, or so on till the node is interactive. Here, i am guessing the parent is the scene. You will have to implement some functionality in the touch delegates of the scene which 'hand over' the touch to the node which lies on the touch point.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been experiencing. I was hoping there was an easier way.Thanks @akashg.

Comment: Is it possible to receive touch events in the Scene AND SpriteNode?
I'm trying to build a UI where effects are handle by the the sprite subclass, and navigation logic by the scene.

Comment: @Veilkrand you can handle touches at the scene level and then check if there are nodes at the touchPoint using the `nodesAtPoint:` method.

Comment: @ZeMoon but I want to handle touches at sprite level AND scene level. As described: at sprite level for effects, at scene level for UI navigation logic.

Comment: @Veilkrand This is worth a different question altogether. I would advise you to do the same, and then I can post an answer properly there.

Comment: @ZeMoon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987142/receive-touch-events-at-skscene-and-skspritenode-in-spritekit

Answer (score 8):

Sprite Kit uses the zPosition value only to determine the hit testing and drawing order.

So you could put all your sprites higher than 0 if you don't want to hit them. And then so a simple logic test is zPostion>0