# sprite kit touch userInteractionEnabled = true

Tags: ios

hi I'm trying to have a sprite overlay set as water with alpha set to 0.3
and other sprites underneath as fishes  but i can't touch the fish as the water sprite swallows the touches

from this post  [[iOS7 Sprite Kit how to disable touches on a sprite to make it "tap through"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481939/ios7-sprite-kit-how-to-disable-touches-on-a-sprite-to-make-it-tap-through][1])
It says to subclass  SKSpriteNode so after reading up on subclassing
i made this https://www.dropbox.com/s/mt067syvbvkmhjb/newClass.zip?dl=0
i can't see where I'm going wrong? any help would be good cheers

my GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene
{
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
  let fishsprite  = fish(imageNamed: "fish")
    fishsprite.position = CGPoint(x: 512, y:350)
    fishsprite.zPosition = 1
    fishsprite.name = "fish"
    addChild(fishsprite)

    let watersprite  = water(imageNamed: "water")
   watersprite.position = CGPoint(x: 512, y: 360)
   watersprite.zPosition = 3
    watersprite.alpha = 0.3
    watersprite.name = "Water"
    addChild(watersprite)
}
```

}

my water class

```
 import SpriteKit
 class water : SKSpriteNode
 {
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
 {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

init(imageNamed: String) {
    let waterTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
    super.init(texture: waterTexture, color: nil, size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    userInteractionEnabled = false // blocks the touches from everything
   // userInteractionEnabled = true //gets  the touches but stop fish getting them
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
    {

 //                      let location = touch.locationInNode(scene)
 //                   let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
 //                      println(touchedNode.zPosition)
 //     

    }
}

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:   UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
    {

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches
    {

    }
}
```

}

my fish class

```
  import Foundation
  import SpriteKit
   class fish : SKSpriteNode
  {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

init(imageNamed: String)
{
    let fishTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
    super.init(texture: fishTexture, color: nil, size: fishTexture.size())
    userInteractionEnabled = true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(scene)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        println(touchedNode)
        zPosition = 15
        let liftUp = SKAction.scaleTo(1.2, duration: 0.2)
        runAction(liftUp, withKey: "pickup")
        let wiggleIn = SKAction.scaleXTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)
        let wiggleOut = SKAction.scaleXTo(1.2, duration: 0.2)
        let wiggle = SKAction.sequence([wiggleIn, wiggleOut])
        let wiggleRepeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(wiggle)
        runAction(wiggleRepeat, withKey: "wiggle")
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(scene)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        touchedNode.position = location
        touchedNode.zPosition = 15
        println(touchedNode)
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches
    {
        zPosition = 2
        let dropDown = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)
        runAction(dropDown, withKey: "drop")
        removeActionForKey("wiggle")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled = false // blocks the touches from everything
` I don't believe that it is blocked from everything. You should find out what is receiving the touch (possibly the scene).

Comment: Have you tried changing `let location = touch.locationInNode(scene)` to `let location = touch.locationInNode(self)`?

Comment: Are you sure that touchesBegan from fish class is executed ? I see you have logging inserted there. What println(touchedNode) say ?

Comment: Another question, why are you overriding the `touches` methods in your water class if they aren't going to be used?

Comment: thanks for your help  Ben  . "You should find out what is receiving the touch (possibly the scene)." how would i find this cheers   "Have you tried changing let location = touch.locationInNode(scene) to let location = touch.locationInNode(self)? " yes   still the same      "why are you overriding the touches methods in your water class if they aren't going to be used? " desperation  thanks Whirlwind  the touches from the fish class is exacuted if the water sprite isn't blocking it

Comment: I think this is just a stupid behavior of Sprite Kit. Your scene should be the one receiving the touches. You could detect which node is being touched in the scene and handle things there.

Comment: hi ben that would work so much better

Comment: hi if i do this                                                                                                           let location = touch.locationInNode(self.scene)
      let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)                                                       let allnodes = nodesAtPoint(location)
        println("node \(touchedNode.name)")
      println("arrayofnodes \(allnodes)")// this is empty
println(" nodes at the point location\(self.scene!.nodesAtPoint(location))") // this is the same? but gives me the info ????

Answer (score 2):

Hey I figured out a little workaround,

Whichever node you want to tap through,

Set the name of the node "Overlay"

Now that this node stands out from other nodes underneath

You can use this code in touched began

```
        for touch in touches {

           let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

           var allNodesTouched = nodesAtPoint(location)

           allNodesTouched.forEach({ (nodeTouched) in

               if nodeTouched.name == "Overlay" {

                   let I = allNodesTouched.indexOf(nodeTouched)
                   allNodesTouched.removeAtIndex(I!)
            }
        })

           if let selectedNode = allNodesTouched.first {

       }
    }
```

Now you can use the selectedNode

Comment: This solution works, however, I just know that somewhere down the road this is going to cause me problems.  Thanks for the workaround!