# Receive touch events at SKScene AND SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

Building a UI with buttons as SKSpriteNode's. Button sprites receive touch events to handle special effects (elastic scaling effects)
But I need the SKScene to handle the touch events at the same time to handle UI navigation logic.

How would be possible to both (sprite AND scene) to handle these touch events?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/bobmoff/7110052. It's in Obj-c, hope that's not an issue

Comment: @ZeMoon this is interesting, however I can't apply it to this case. I'm looking for the Scene to receive the touch event at the same time as the sprite.

Comment: You can [forward the touch event](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html) to the scene after the button receives/handles the touch. You can also disable touches in the button and handle touches in the scene and call a method in the button class to scale, highlight, etc. the button.

Comment: Probably my approach was not entirely valid at all. I've resolved the issue where the sprite receives the touch and notifies the scene via a selector a la UIButton.