# Objective C - How to disable touch on 2nd Sknode when 1st SKnode is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have two **SKNodes, RMnode and RLnode,** that receive touches. Unfortunately, at the same time.

I tried disabling the touch on the **2nd SKnode,** when 1st has been touched and vice versa, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Is there perhaps another approach to this?

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint Rubyposition = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self selectNodeForTouch:Rubyposition]; //a helper method that asks the scene (self) for the node that is on the position touchLocation.

    SKNode *RMnode = [self nodeAtPoint:Rubyposition];
    SKNode *RLnode = [self nodeAtPoint:Rubyposition];

    if ([RLnode.name isEqualToString:@"Ruby1"]) {
        if(_TouchOnRubyRL == NO){
            _TouchOnRubyRL = YES;
            //RMnode.userInteractionEnabled = NO; //Not working
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRL];
        }
        else if(_TouchOnRubyRL == YES){
            _TouchOnRubyRL = NO;
            //RMnode.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //not working
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRL];
        }
    }
    if ([RMnode.name isEqualToString:@"Ruby2"]) {
        if(_TouchOnRubyRM == NO){
            _TouchOnRubyRM = YES;
            //RLnode.userInteractionEnabled = NO; //Not working
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRM];
        }
        else if(_TouchOnRubyRM == YES){
            _TouchOnRubyRM = NO;
            //RLnode.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //Not working
            [self.level ActivatedBricks:_TouchOnRubyRM];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does selectNodeForTouch actually do - this is not clear. Where is this shown method - in the scene or on the node? Are both nodes actually at the touch location? Changing userInteractionEnabled within the handler will not alter the reaction to the current touch - the event has already triggered so that can only affect future events. Can you explain in more detail what nodes you have and what you want to happen when they are touched.

Comment: @AliBeadle The helper method is in the scene. It is a helper method that asks the scene (self) for the node that is on the position touchLocation. Then an if-statement checks if the selected node is one of the 2 ruby nodes, and "activates" or "deactivates" it.  I just want, for now, to disable touches on one of the nodes, if the other has been touched first and vice versa. I.e. 1st ruby touched --> disable touch on 2nd ruby node. 1st ruby touched for a second time --> enable touch on 2nd ruby node, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason setting the node's userInteractionEnabled is not working as you expect is that your touchesBegan is in the scene, not the sprite. userInteractionEnabled only allows/disallows touches to the SKNode it is a property of (an SKScene is an SKNode too) - and in your code the scene's userInteractionEnabled is always true so the touch always gets through to the scene's touchesBegan method (your sprite's touchesBegan **is** being disabled - but you are not overriding it so you don't notice).

To use userInteractionEnabled in this way you would need to subclass the sprites themselves and handle touches within the subclassed sprite - then setting userInteractionEnabled will work as you expect.

If you do not want to refactor your code like that, you could mark each sprite as 'untouchable' in some other way ([this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515593/2466193) suggests using the SKNode's existing zPosition property) and then use this in your scene before accepting the touch (e.g. if touchedNode.zPosition != 0 ...).

Comment: That explains it.... :D thanks for the help, it solved the problem. I changed the touchesBegan from the scene to the sprite.